# How do we customise FB share function without affecting SEO?

Tags: facebook, seo

FB share currently pulls the page title tag and first body text by default.

However our title tags are optimised for SEO and we want to customise what people see when the website is shared.

I thought this might be a solution:

```
<meta name="title" content="title" />
<meta name="description" content="description " />
<link rel="image_src" href="thumbnail_image" / >
```

But have been told this will still conflict with the SEO? Can anyone help?

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't make sense. People also see your "SEO-optimized" titles...when they actually search. Why are they not a problem there such that they *will* be a problem on Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

[The share button is going away](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-20037008-93.html?part=rss&subj=news&tag=2547-1_3-0-20). The Like button allows you to set the title that shows when the web page is liked so this should solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting fresh news. +1